# Disable Java JIT compilation of specific functions

Tags: java, c++, hook, jit

I am currently working on a c++ project that involves injecting a dll into the java process (minecraft), one major component of this project requires that any java function i specify must remain as interpreted and not become compiled. If I disable the compiler fully then there is a huge drop in performance, making the game unplayable even high-end hardware.

What im looking for is some way to allow function compilation to work as normal, but prevent a few target functions from compiling.

Alternatively I could also use a system where im notified that my target function is about to be, or has just been compiled, and be given the new pointer to it, but I feel the approach of compilation prevention is more practical to do.

I do not have the option to modify/specify arguments to java during the launch of the application, i cant do something like -X:CompileCommand=exclude,the/package/and/Class,methodName. Would it maybe be possible to somehow add functions I want to exclude during runtime?
Or does anyone know of some place I could place a hook and monitor which functions the jvm plans on compiling, and prevent the ones I specify?

I have thought about hooking compiler or GC threads but this dosnt seem like a safe or reliable approach, im told it would have a lot of drawbacks.

Comment: It's difficult to understand the question like this, maybe you can give some example.

Comment: I don't understand why you care about the distinction between interpreted and compiled functions? Surely you just call them and/or hot reload them?

Comment: @Botje I am performing detour hooks, the problem is that the jvm will constantly recompile functions every few minutes breaking the hooks I place. Therefore I need: to turn off this compilation OR be aware when the recompilation is about to take place